# Calculate results automatically on keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been having hard time on getting the exact value between two input values using `keyup function`. First I get the exact result to calculate and display the result in another input tag but when I add another it displays wrong result. To understand what I mean just check the code below.

HTML:

```
<input id="ivpd" type="text" name="input_vat_per_document" placeholder="Input VAT per Document">
<input id="gta" type="text" readonly>
<input id="gp" type="text" readonly>
```

JS:

```
$('#ivpd').keyup(function(){
  var percentage = 12 / 100;
  var gta = $('#ivpd').val() / percentage;
  var gp = $('#ivpd').val() + $('#gta').val();
  if (gta == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || gta == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || isNaN(gta))
      gta = "N/A"; // OR 0
  $('#gta').val(gta);
  $('#gp').val(gp);
});
```

For example:
If I input `964.25` in `ivpd`, `gta` will be `8035.75` but `gp` displays `964.298035.75` which is a wrong result. It shoud be `ivpd` + `gta`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` property of `input-elements` always return [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) and if any of the operand is of type `string`, [`Addition(+)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()) operator will do `string concatenation` operation not `addition`.

> Cast `input-value` to `Number` and then manipulate.

[**`Unary plus (+)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), *The `unary plus operator` precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a `number`, if it isn't already.*

***Note:*** `Number` could be used as well instead of `Unary plus (+)`

```js
$('#ivpd').keyup(function() {
  var percentage = 12 / 100;
  var gta = +this.value / percentage;
  var gp = +this.value + +$('#gta').val();
  if (gta == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || gta == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || isNaN(gta))
    gta = "N/A"; // OR 0
  $('#gta').val(gta);
  $('#gp').val(gp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ivpd" type="text" name="input_vat_per_document" placeholder="Input VAT per Document">
<input id="gta" type="text" readonly>
<input id="gp" type="text" readonly>
```

Comment: I noticed that in my previous code it only concat input values like strings.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to multiply ivpd and gta values with 1

```
          var gta = $('#ivpd').val() / percentage;
        var ivpd= $('#ivpd').val();
        var gta =gta*1;
        var gp =(ivpd *1)+ (gta*1);
```

codepen url for reference- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/EyPVVE

Comment: Thanks but it gives me `8999.29` in `gp`. Value expected should be `9000.04`

Comment: var gta = $('#ivpd').val() / percentage;
  var ivpd= $('#ivpd').val();
  var gta =gta*1;
  var gp =(ivpd *1)+ (gta*1);
  console.log(gta+gp);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var gp = parseFloat($('#ivpd').val()) + parseFloat($('#gta').val());
```